# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, dart-null-safety

This is my my code and null safety is enabled. I am not able to understand why I am facing the mentioned error where I am storing the value for "videoId".

Also, what can be another way to store this value for using later as I don't think that its the best way?
P.S.- It works when null safety is disabled.

[image: error message]

Comment: better to place your code inside a 'code sample' tag rather than a image. This will help others re-run your code

Answer (score 0):

First don't assign a value for your var videoId inside the player initialization!
before initializing the controller Add:

```
videoId = ....;
```

Then

```
YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId:videoId ...);
```

if your widget.youtubelink is a String, assign it to your videoId without calling convert uriToId

Comment: I did that but now facing another error- The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

Comment: Yeah, write this.widget.youtubeLink -> access your widget using this

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
YoutubePlayer(
  controller: _youtubePlayerController = 
     YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(Links!).toString(),

         flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
            autoPlay: false,
           ),
     ),
```